# How to overcome template installation problems in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I'm trying to deploy a Joomla 1.5 site developed locally. I'm not using the latest version because some extensions that I need are for 1.5 only.

After migrating the database and contents a lot of issues appeared - most of them I believe have to do with Joom!Fish.

Therefore I decided to install a fresh copy of Joomla 1.5 on the targeted server (Yahoo Small Business host), install the template and rebuild the contents.

The problem has to do with the second step: installing the template. I install it using the Extension Manager (without any errors), it shows up in Extension Manager -> Templates, but it doesn't show up in the Template Manager (therefore it can't be enabled). I get the exact same disappointing result when manually FTP-ing the template files. The "jos_templates_menu" table didn't had an entry corresponding to my template; manually adding it didn't had any positive result. I believe that *templatedetails.xml* is correct.

I've tested other templates (free online ones). Most of them show up in Template Manager.

Odd is the fact that if I try to install my template on a freshly installed Joomla 1.5 site (on localhost), everything is OK.

Can anybody please share some thoughts (from experience or not) with respect to this particular issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue many times in the past, and can say with near certainty that it roots back to your templatedetails.xml file.  Make sure that the names that are being used all match exactly (usually case-sensitive) because Joomla starts by looking at the subfolders found in the Templates folder, and proceeding from there with the templatedetails.xml file that it finds in each.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I've said, I'm pretty sure that _templatedetails.xml_ is OK. But two opinions are always better then one. Perhaps you could take a look at [templatedetails.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5224908/ScienceEtReligion/template/templatedetails.xml).

Comment: _templatedetails.xml_ vs _templateDetails.xml_. Could this be a problem?